# Submit a "Person field" via Infopath & Webservice to a Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I wonder if anyone knows a solution to this problem:

I am submitting some fields to a Sharepoint List. In detail some values are passed to the Sharepoint lists.asmx Webservice.

Problem is: I want to pass a person into a data field, which is a "Person or Group" field.
So I have to pass a string in this format: "1;#Username,#someMoreValues" respectively "ID;#" in enough.
But this ID is an internal ID, which Sharepoint uses for a reason, I don't want to know ;)

Is there any chance, to get this ID via the Sharepoint webservices?
The userprofileservice.asmx and the getuserinfo.asmx will return anything but the ID.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to check and make sure this is for sure what you are looking for, but I'm reasonably sure that what you want is to use the People.asmx web service, SearchPrincipals method. It returns a collection of user principals, and one of the fields is UserInfoID .

Comment: Thanks, it returns the ID, I was looking for!
(So i got some new questions, but that will be a new post)

Answer (score 1):

Use Id equal to "-1".

Example: -1; #corp\username

More information is [here](http://connect.nintex.com/forums/thread/1826.aspx)